# Video playing issue in windows azure web site

Tags: azure-web-app-service

This is the first time I am working with `Azure website`. I have successfully deployed my website into Azure website cloud hosting space. Everything is working pretty fine, and as desired. But I am facing issues in my video page. Am providing 2 urls, hosted in the same location.

1. http://masan.azurewebsites.net/video/demo.html
2. http://masan.azurewebsites.net/video/demo1.html

First video is playing (.mp4), after adding the necessary `mimeMap` tag in my `web.config`file. First `demo.html` contains a video being called from an external url.

Second video in demo1.html (.mp4) contain video hosted in the same server as the page, which is not playing.

Could somebody please guide me, what should I do to make my second page to also start playing the .mp4 video

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you all, there was no issue only, since the video in demo1.html was of wrong format, it was not playing.
So the answer to the above is: Just need to add the mimeMap tag in web.config, will work seamlessly. Thank you.